# Specifiy minimum number of join points in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this joining table:

```
 CREATE TABLE [TagMap](
[intItemId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[intTagId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TagMap_intItemId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
[intItemId] ASC,
[intTagId] ASC
 ))
```

My sproc discovers the tags that are associated with a seedItemId and then selects other intItemIds that are associated with those tags, like this:

```
 declare @baseTags table    (intTagId bigint primary key clustered);

INSERT INTO @baseTags (intTagId)
SELECT TOP 20 t1.intTagId
FROM   TagMap t1
WHERE t1.intItemId = 776

 SELECT TOP 500 t1.intItemId
 FROM   TagMap t1
      JOIN @baseTags t2
       ON t1.intTagId = t2.intTagId
 GROUP  BY t1.intItemId
 ORDER  BY Count(*) DESC
```

What I need to to is specify a minimum number of tag associations - say 10 - between two intItemIds below which a value is not returned. In other words in the TagMap table can find ten or more intTagIds that two intItemIds have in common, it's good and we select it - otherwise ignore it.

So, for example given this data:

```
 CREATE TABLE #TagMap(
 [intItemId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 [intTagId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TagMap_intItemId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
 [intItemId] ASC,
 [intTagId] ASC
 ))

 insert into #TagMap
 (intItemId, intTagId)
 values 
 (1, 100),(1, 200),(1, 300),
 (2, 100),(2, 200),         (2, 500),(2, 600),
 (3, 100),                  (3, 500),(3, 600)
```

Assume the match threshold is two.

If the seed is intItemId 1, then only intItemId 2 should be returned (it has two matching tag Ids: 100 and 200, while intItemId 3 has one: 100, which is below the threshold).

If the seed is intItemId 2, then both intItemId 1 and 3 should be returned (intItemId 1 matches the tag Ids 100 and 200, while intItemId 3 matches the tag Ids 500 and 600).

If the seed is intItemId 3, then only intItemId 2 should be returned (it has two matching tag Ids: 500 and 600, while intItemId has one: 100 which is below the threshold).

Any ideas how to do this, please?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  [foreign].intItemID
FROM
  #TagMap    AS [primary]
INNER JOIN
  #TagMap    AS [foreign]
    ON [foreign].intTagID = [primary].intTagID
WHERE
  [primary].intItemID = 1
GROUP BY
  [foreign].intItemID
HAVING
  COUNT(distinct [foreign].intTagID) >= @threshold
```

Note, however, that this scales pretty badly; because the `JOIN` searches for "has ***any*** of these tags", and then only in the `HAVING` clause can you specify "has ***all*** of these tags".

From my experience you can make minor optimisations, but the most rewarding approach I found was to cache the results into a more standard mapping table.  Updating them as and when necessary.  (The contents of the tags data changing very infrequently.)

Comment: Thanks for the warning about the performance - that may come back to bite me when I use this on the real data.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do it (vary `@InterestItem` to 1,2,3, and it seems to generate the result you've asked for):

```
declare @InterestItem int
set @InterestItem = 1
declare @Threshold int
set @Threshold = 2

select
    tm2.intItemId,
    COUNT(*)
from
    #TagMap tm1
        inner join
    #TagMap tm2
        on
            tm1.intTagId = tm2.intTagId and
            tm2.intItemId <> tm1.intItemId
where
    tm1.intItemId = @InterestItem
group by
    tm2.intItemId
having
    COUNT(*) >= @Threshold
```

I'm currently including the `COUNT` in the result set, but that isn't needed to make this work.